# At most one homomorphism between two groups

Tags: group-homomorphism, free-groups

Let $S$ be a set, and $F$, $G$ be groups. 
Let $f: S \rightarrow F$ and $g: S \rightarrow G$ be functions.

I want to prove the following:

If $f(S)$ generates $F$, then there exists **at most** one homomorphism
$\psi:F \rightarrow G$ such that the following diagram commutes.

[image: Figure]

I know that for every $s \in S$, $\psi(f(s))$ should be defined as $g(s)$, 
and so $\psi(f(s)^{-1})$ should be defined as $g(s)^{-1}$.

And because $\{f(s): s \in S\} \cup \{f(s)^{-1} : s \in S \}$ is a generating set of $F$, the mapping $\psi$ can be extended to the whole domain $F$ as a homomorphism.

However, in my mind, I understand the processing, but I couldn't write the proof in the clear way.

Please, help me.

**Edit 1:**

This question is from the section free groups (Lang, Algebra. p. 66)

Before defining the free group, this statement appears.

**Edit 2:**

I edit the title.

If for some $s_1, s_2 \in S$, $f(s_1) = f(s_2)$ and $g(s_1) \neq g(s_2)$, then there does not exist $\psi$.

Comment: What does mean ''(f:S→F) generates F'' ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux It means that "$f(S)$ generates $F$".

Comment: Are $F$ and $G$  free groups, as I suspect according to the tags ?

Comment: @GreginGre No, $F$ and $G$ are just any groups.

Comment: If $F$ is not free, I think your statement is false (even I didn't give it much thoughts)

Comment: @GreginGre Yes, I edit the title, and some contents. My statement means that "there exists at most one homomorphism". It means that if there exists a homomorphism, then it it unique, and sometimes it is possible that homomorphism doesn't exist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $f$ and $g$ are just given maps between sets and $f$ is injective. If you want the diagram to commute, this defines where $\psi$ maps the generators of $F$. What you have to show is if you have a mapping of the group generators, there is a unique way to extend it to a group homomorphism.

So let $\sigma \in F$ be arbitrary. Then $\sigma$ can be written as $\sigma=a_1^{n_1}\cdot ... \cdot a_k^{n_k}$ where the $a_i$ are generators and the $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because the group is free, this representation is unique. As we already know $\psi(a_i)$ and want $\psi$ to be a group homomorphism, this defines a unique value for $\psi(\sigma) \in G$. You can check that this definition of $\psi$ actually gives a group homomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I edit the title. I understand when $f$ is injective. what might happen when $f$ is not injective?

Comment: @DoyunNam If $f$ is not injective, there might not be a group homomorphism to make the diagram commute.

Comment: @quarague: apparently, $F$ is not supposed to be free on $S$ , so your argument does not work.

Comment: @GreginGre Similar answer as before :-) If $F$ is not free, there might not be a group homomorphism to make the diagram commute. However, if such a homomorphism exists, it is unique and can be constructed as in my answer.